# Can't get any result with laravel query builder

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

What is the different between laravel query builder

```
//fecth query 
$query = DB::table('order_details')
->select('order_code', 'product_name', 'qty', 'order_details.total_price as subtotal')
->leftJoin('orders', 'order_details.order_id', '=', 'orders.id')
->whereRaw('DATE_FORMAT(orders.order_date, "%Y-%m-%d") BETWEEN ? AND ?', ["'".$start_date."'", "'".$end_date."'"]);
var_dump($query->get());
```

and this mysql query

```
 select `order_code`, `product_name`, `qty`, `order_details`.`total_price`as `subtotal` 
 from `order_details` 
 left join `orders` on `order_details`.`order_id`=`orders`.`id` 
 where DATE_FORMAT(orders.order_date, "%Y-%m-%d") between '2017-07-01' and '2017-07-31'
```

I can't get any result from laravel query builder but I did on the mysql even though I have the same start and end date input. Is there anything wrong with my laravel query?

Edit : 
Hmmmm.... somehow after I changed the where clause to this

```
->whereRaw(DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(orders.order_date, "%Y-%m-%d") BETWEEN "'.$start_date.'" AND "'.$end_date.'"'));
```

it gives me the same result as the mysql query, but why though. Do I use the whereRaw() correctly for the first where clause? 
It didn't give me the result if I'm using this whereBetween() too

```
->whereBetween(DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(orders.order_date, "%Y-%m-%d")'), ["'".$start_date."'", "'".$end_date."'"]);
```

Do I make a mistake in the first whereRaw() and the whereBetween() usage and where is the mistake? Do whereRaw() can only pass array of integer? When I tried to see the query log on first whereRaw() and the whereBetween() using this code

```
DB::enableQueryLog();
var_dump($query->get());    
var_dump(DB::getQueryLog()[0]['query']);
```

I get this result

```
"select `order_code`, `product_name`, `qty`, `order_details`.`total_price` as `subtotal` 
from `order_details` 
left join `orders` on `order_details`.`order_id` = `orders`.`id` 
where DATE_FORMAT(orders.order_date, "%Y-%m-%d") BETWEEN ? AND ?"
```

It seems the '?' value wasn't replaced by **$start_date** and **$end_date value**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the quotes from your bindings in the whereRaw

```
->whereRaw('DATE_FORMAT(orders.order_date, "%Y-%m-%d") BETWEEN ? AND ?', [$start_date, $end_date]);
```

Also, as a recommendation, there is probably no need to use DATE_FORMAT either. If you are trying to do that date comparison where you only have the Date part , just alter your bindings:

```
    ->whereRaw('orders.order_date BETWEEN ? AND ?', 
         [$start_date . ' 00:00:00', $end_date . ' 23:59:59']]);
```

Comment: Thanks it works :), but I believe I've done that already and it still doesn't give me a single result. Maybe I just forget to change the date range input in the application and no record present it that date range.